# outputcache mvc3 only logged out user caching

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, outputcache

Is there a way to use the OutputCache attribute to cache the results of only logged out users and reevaluate for logged in users example:

What I'd Like

```
[OutputCache(onlycacheanon = true)]
public ActionResult GetPhoto(id){
   var photo = getPhoto(id);
   if(!photo.issecured){
      return photo...
   }
   return getPhotoOnlyIfCurrentUserHasAccess(id);
   //otherwise return default photo so please don't cache me
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `VaryByCustom` property in `[OutputCache]`.

Then override [HttpApplication.GetVaryByCustomString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.getvarybycustomstring%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and check `HttpContext.Current.User.IsAuthenticated`.

- Return `"NotAuthed"` or similar if not authenticated (activating cache)
- `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` to invalidate the cache

Comment: That's the very thing I was missing thank you.  I didn't realize null disabled caching.

Comment: Didn't know it was available. Thank you :)

Comment: `null` **does NOT** disable the cache. I've tried that solution on the sample project and it just caches separately for authenticated and non authenticated users...

Comment: @Cheburek You can return Guid.NewGuid().ToString() instead of null, which would make every request unique.   But it would have some performance implications.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I implemented the above.

In Global.asax.cs:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
{
    if (custom == "UserId")
    {
        if (context.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return context.User.Identity.Name;
        }
        return null;
    }

    return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);
}
```

Usage in Output Cache Attribute:

```
 [OutputCache(Duration = 30, VaryByCustom = "UserId" ...
 public ActionResult MyController()
 {
    ...
```